# Apollo and 3rd party rest api. Should I store the 3rd party data in a database

Tags: postgresql, rest, graphql, apollo

We are setting up a new development that does data aggregation, manipulation and visualizations for 3rd party data. This data is available via a 3rd party rest api that has a lot of unique and not well thought out intricacies. Example is some of the data is returned with pagination while others just need to be queried with offsets until no more items are returned. The data from a single rest endpoint can be returned in multiple formats depending on what information the data for that particular item contains. The data is also linked to a particular user so each of our users will only be accesses their own data from the 3rd party.

We want to use apollo and graphql. We will need a postgres database to store our user settings. Our front end will be built in react.

I am wondering though if we should use apollo to consume the 3rd party api as a datasource directly when needed or if we should regularly call the 3rd party api and store the data in our own postgres database.

If we store the data retrieved in our own database it may give us added flexibility but we have to pay data storage fees. It may also decrease the time needed to generate reports for our users because we will not need to wait for the 3rd party rest api to respond. We will need to code for a service that then regularly polls the 3rd party api and updates our database but that should be easier to do.

Any help or insight would be appreciated. Perhaps I am thinking about the problem all wrong...

Comment: This is a question that calls for an opinion and as such is likely to be closed. The storage fees may or not be pertinent but db synchronization invariably adds complexity. OTOH the original REST api may not just perform well for the queries you need. I'm facing a similar design problem at the moment and it's causing similar tradeoffs.

Comment: I'm glad to hear I'm not the only one facing this tradeoff. The db synchronization adds complexity and even basic questions like how often should we call the 3rd party rest api to update our database with any changes do not have straight forward answers. We may bite the bullet and use a db because it may offer more flexibility moving forward with the ability to easier add new features.